# Jquery Ajax Get Div

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, find, response

I'm having trouble with ajax response.

my .php file generates a table

```
    <div class="result">
        <tr class="distr">
           <td><input name="somename" value="value"></input</td>
           <td>..more input</td>
           ...more <tds>
       </tr>
    <div>
```

.js file

```
//...unrelated code up here

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphpfile.php",
    data: "data that creates table",
    success: function(r) {
        var getdata = $(r).filter(".result");
        console.log(getdat);
    }
});
```

my main file has

```
<table class="tbl">
   <tr>
       <td><input></input></td>
       ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the table that is generated by my php file to be appended to

```
<table class="tbl">
```

but the response I get is only

```
<input>...</input>
<input>...</input>
some other div children here
<input>...</input>
some text
```

instead of everything in

```
<div class="result">
```

Can someone explain to me how this works.
I've also tried .find(".result") instead of .filter()
Oh and I dont want that div returned, just the table inside of it.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, all this looks weird as I'm typing.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting that `tr` into a `div`, when you could use a `table`?

Comment: yea sorry it is in a table, I just forgot to put it on here.

Comment: Ah I checked again and yes I didn't have table there. I guess it skipped <tr> and <td> because there wasnt a table, It works now,  used a Div without thinking, so its easy to filter it, but didnt expect this result, Works now, Thanks

Comment: I am happy it was solved. Added an answer so you can accept it and thus mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `div` with a `table`, so it will be proper HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `jQuery.get ()`

```
$.get( "myphpfile.php", { param1: "p1", param2: "p2" } )
    .done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( ".result" );
});
```

Update:

```
$(".result").load("myphpfile.php .result", { param1: "p1", param2: "p2" })
```

Comment: I tried this already, for some reason when I use .find() it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please check updated answer. I used this in my projects. Hope this works